# How to increase accuracy of occupancy prediction?

Tags: python, pandas, random-forest, data-analysis, prediction

I have a project that's aimed to predict the amount of occupants at my local gym given the date and weather.

[Here's my Kaggle kernel](https://www.kaggle.com/clumpus/weather-vs-occupancy?scriptVersionId=21094022)

I have two datasets, occupants on a given hour and weather on a given hour.
My process is that I combine these two datasets, and using Occupants as the target.
However, when I implement a regression algorithm I can only reach a prediction score of 57%.

I'd love any advice on how to modify my solution to achieve better predictions?

Thank you.

Comment: Consider moving the question to [Data Science Stack](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

To Improve the accuracy:

- Do more feature engineering.
- You can convert your categorical variable into one hot encoded values.
- You can make one more feature stating morning, afternoon, evening, night using hour from timestamp and also you can add 'weekday/weekend' column.
- You have not done EDA much. Check for outliers and remove them.